# Why is it correct to conceptualize LIGO's mirrors as "test masses?"

Tags: general-relativity, gravitational-waves

In the LIGO paper on the first detection of gravitational waves, they have a [diagram](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Simplified_diagram_of_an_Advanced_LIGO_detector.png) of one of the interferometers in which they label the mirrors with the conceptual label of "test masses." The collaboration has a [page](https://www.ligo.caltech.edu/page/optics) with some photos of the mirrors, where they mention that the masses are 40 kg, although obviously the actual mass would be irrelevant.

What is a good conceptual explanation of why it is valid to think of the experiment in terms of these four test masses, pretending that they're floating in space? After some helpful discussion in comments with Sean E. Lake, several possibilities occur to me:

1. Even if the mirrors were anchored to the ground rather than suspended loosely, the ground is in some sense so elastic that it wouldn't matter that the ground exists. To matter, the ground would have to be so stiff that signals would propagate in it at speeds on the order of $c$. Actually, signals propagate in it at the speed of seismological waves, which are many orders of magnitude lower. Suspension rather than rigid anchoring is required because of noise from ground vibration.
2. If the mirrors were anchored to the ground, then the detected signal would be zero, even in the absence of noise from ground vibration.
3. Logically, if the metric in general relativity is to mean anything, then it must relate to rigid measuring rods. The ground underlying one arm of the detector is a measuring rod.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As part of the vibration isolation process, [they're suspended](http://www.gwoptics.org/hardware_hacks/mirror_suspension/) ([see also](https://www.ligo.caltech.edu/news/ligo20170216)), not rigidly coupled to the ground. So, they are connected, but the response to ground vibrations is going to be very frequency dependent, and in the relevant frequency range and amplitude range, they're just hanging there in space.

"To matter, the ground would have to be so stiff that signals would propagate in it at speeds on the order of c." I don't think so. What your describing is a a system with a resonant response and quality factor (width of resonant response). So the limiting factor is how it responds to the relevant frequency and if the quality factor is high enough for the response to build to observable before the signal ends.

Comment: Good to know that they're suspended. However, the question isn't about ground vibrations. Are you claiming that in the absence of ground vibrations, rigid coupling to the ground *would* or *would not* make a difference in the results?

Comment: I'm claiming that in the relevant frequency range the suspension is designed to make the mirrors respond in the same way a mass coupled to nothing would be, or at least as close as they can get.

Comment: OK, but I feel like you're not addressing the conceptual question. Are you saying you don't know what would happen if they were rigidly coupled to the ground, in the absence of ground vibrations?

Comment: I'm addressing this, "What is a good conceptual explanation of why it is valid to think of the experiment in terms of these four test masses, pretending that they're floating in space?" with "Because they went to a lot of effort to make the system behave that way."

In the absence of noise, with a sufficiently rigid system, it wouldn't see the gravity waves for the same reason space-time expansion doesn't cause physical bodies to expand along with it.

Comment: I don't think I buy the argument by analogy with cosmological expansion. Cosmological expansion does, in theory, cause strains in material objects. The acceleration, in an object of size $L$, is on the order of $L\ddot{a}/a$, which simply happens to be small because $\ddot{a}/a$ is on the order of the square of the Hubble constant, or about $10^{-35}\ \text{s}^{-2}$. See http://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/9803097v1 .

Comment: Good point. Disregard that half of the comment, please.

Comment: Maybe we could continue this discussion in chat at a later time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71948/discussion-between-sean-e-lake-and-ben-crowell).